# Why does this simple shell code give the output as "/dev/fd/11"?

Tags: shell, unix

I was trying out some redirection in my mac zsh shell.

I see that `echo <(echo $c)` outputs `/dev/fd/11`. I have no idea why this happens. Can someone explain?

Note: It doesn't matter if `$c` is initialised or not. 
`echo < ''` returns `zsh: no such file or directory:` , so I am at a loss understanding what's going on.

Comment: `echo` doesn't read from standard input, so `echo < ...` doesn't make sense even if a valid file name (which the empty string is not) is used with `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process expansion effectively "expands" to a file name. You are passing that file name as the argument to `echo`, which it dutifully writes back to standard output. If you had written

```
cat <(echo $c)
```

you would get as output, as I think you expected, the output of the command `echo $c`, because `cat` would open `/dev/fd/11` for reading and output its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe

Looks like `<(COMMAND)` is slightly different that a the `<` (STDIN redirect) command

> Pipes and input redirects shove content onto the STDIN stream. Process
>   substitution runs the commands, saves their output to a special
>   temporary file and then passes that file name in place of the command.
>   Whatever command you are using treats it as a file name. Note that the
>   file created is not a regular file but a named pipe that gets removed
>   automatically once it is no longer needed.